# What is the correct way to preserve protocol (http or https) when doing a redirect through "window.location.href = ..."?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm redirecting a user on a website from one page to another by using:

```
window.location.href = "http://page.com/new_url";
```

But problem is that sometimes website is accessed from HTTP, but sometimes from HTTPS.

How do I make the redirect work and preserve the protocol?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want a protocol-relative URL:

```
//example.com/path
```

Comment: Wow this is something new! Never saw `//` url before :)

Comment: Now big problem @SLaks - I want it to be hostname independent, too. Like when I test on my laptop I've `//localhost`, but when test on real metal then `//domain.com`... How do this?

Comment: Then you want a relative URL.  (`/path`)